# Maximum size of value field in Google Properties service

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am a Google Scripts newbie following the documentation at:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties

I would like to store multiple values for a single key by appending a pipe and an extra value. eg if the key is named "USERNAME" I would like to append values by doing "Bob|Mary|Martin" etc

Is there a maximum size of entries I can create before I get a crash? Where can I check the maximum size of a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't an exact answer to your question as far as I know, as the keys are limited by size, not by character.
The maximum size is defined as 9kb / value on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas
1kb is roughly equal to 1024 characters, so the maximum size of a value is around 9216 characters, which is more than enough for your purposes I'm sure.
If you are still concerned, you could try storing each username as a key, and using getKeys() to get an array of usernames, though that means that you would not be able to store additional properties.

Comment: "1kb is roughly equal to 1024 characters" Can you clarify please where this information comes from? Does it depend on the language, for example, English / Chinese?